# Chrome tabs.onActivated updating only current tab

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a basic chrome extension that fires when the user switches to a new active tab. In the background page the URL is examined and the extension icon changes based on the URL.

```
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function(tabInfo) {
  chrome.tabs.get(tabInfo.tabId, function(tab) {
    update_tab(...)
  });
});
```

This works fine, but the problem I am facing is that by the time the function fires and the decision is made to update the icon, the user can switch tabs again, but the icon is changed based on the previous tab.

How can I handle this more reliability?

Comment: If you are talking about browserAction icon (and slow proces of refreshing), I would suggest you build your logic with pageAction (from my experience is faster). Not sure how it behaves (from speed point of view) now when page action is moved from address bar to toolbar

Comment: I would love to see a solution for this that includes all modern browsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have per-tab browser action icons, so you don't need to track tab switching.

If you use [`chrome.browserAction.setIcon`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#method-setIcon) to update your icon, it takes an optional `tabId` parameter. Same applies to `setTitle`.

If you do this, you need not worry about tab activations; `onUpdated` will inform you of URL changes.

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding the `onUpdated` listener too:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabInfo) {
  chrome.tabs.get(tabInfo.tabId, function(tab) {
    update_tab(...)
  });
});
```

> Fires when the active tab in a window changes. Note that the tab's URL
>   may not be set at the time this event fired, but you can listen to
>   onUpdated events to be notified when a URL is set. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs